# makefile generated using QGIS Plugin builder cannot find pyuic4

Tags: qgis

I have QGIS 2.4 installed using the OSGeo4W installer. I have the bin folder in my path and I can run `pyuic4` successfully on the command line using osgeo4w.bat, but when I try to run the makefile generated by the QGIS plugin builder, I get an error saying:

```
pyuic4 -o ui_LoginDialog.py ui_LoginDialog.ui
make: pyuic4: Command not found
make: *** [ui_LoginDialog.py] Error 127
```

I know the syntax is correct because I can run the first line of that command manually in the command line (under osgeo4w.bat).

Is it possible that the items I have in my PATH are conflicting with the osgeo4w environment? I don't understand how I can run it manually and then it fails in the makefile, in the same osgeo4w session.

My makefile:

```
UIFILES := $(wildcard *.ui)
PYFILES := $(UIFILES:.ui=.py)    

.PHONY: all
all: $(PYFILES)    

%.py: %.ui
    pyuic4 -o $@ $<
```